# Xposed - Detecting Keys Long Press ( Can Detect Normal Press, But not Long Press )

Tags: android, xposed

I'm trying to listen for Keys long press, The keys i'm listen to are Volume Up / Volume Down / Back key, using Xposed I've hooked into a class and managed to listen to them, only 2 problems :

I've added a logcat when volume up is pressed, the problem I'm getting the log 7 times, even though i'm pressing it only once .

I'm not able to listen to Long Press, isLongPressed isn't working .

Here's the code :

```
 public static void init() {

    final Class localClass = XposedHelpers.findClass("com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager", Xposed.CLASS_LOADER);
    XposedBridge.hookAllConstructors(localClass, new XC_MethodHook() {
        protected void afterHookedMethod(final XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam paramAnonymousMethodHookParam)
                throws Throwable {
        }
    });

    XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(localClass, "interceptKeyBeforeQueueing", KeyEvent.class, Integer.TYPE, new XC_MethodHook() {
@Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param)
                throws Throwable {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) param.args[0];
            int code = event.getKeyCode();

            if (code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Log.i(Xposed.TAG, "Back Pressed");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Also, I've tried to put a delay for the long press, the problem is I'm getting the press and the long press, and i'm getting the long press even if i'm not long pressing it.